# Consulta con Query sobre Date()

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, parsear

Tengo una Query realizada sobre Groovy, la cuál me recoge los usuarios que están inactivos en el sistema una vez pasados 30 días:

```
SELECT u.USER_ID,u.NICKNAME, uav_last.ATTR_VALUE LASTSTATUSCHANGED,uav_employee.ATTR_VALUE,trunc(sysdate)-to_date(uav_last.ATTR_VALUE, 'dd-MM-yyyy') " +
"FROM IAMUSER.USERS u " +
"INNER JOIN IAMUSER.USER_ATTRIBUTES ua_last " +
"    ON u.USER_ID = ua_last.USER_ID AND LOWER(ua_last.NAME) = 'jus_laststatuschanged' " +
"INNER JOIN IAMUSER.USER_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES uav_last " +
"    ON uav_last.USER_ATTRIBUTE_ID = ua_last.ID " +
"INNER JOIN IAMUSER.USER_ATTRIBUTES ua_employee " +
"    ON u.USER_ID = ua_employee.USER_ID AND LOWER(ua_employee.NAME) = 'jus_tipoempleado' " +
"INNER JOIN IAMUSER.USER_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES uav_employee " +
"    ON uav_employee.USER_ATTRIBUTE_ID = ua_employee.ID " +
"WHERE trunc(sysdate)-to_date(uav_last.ATTR_VALUE, 'dd-MM-yyyy') >= 30 AND TO_CHAR(uav_employee.ATTR_VALUE) = 'MJU' " +
"AND u.USER_ID = (SELECT u.USER_ID FROM IAMUSER.USERS us,IAMUSER.COMPANY c ,IAMUSER.USER_AFFILIATION ua " +
"WHERE u.USER_ID = ua.USER_ID AND c.COMPANY_ID = ua.COMPANY_ID AND c.COMPANY_NAME = 'ACTIVOS' AND us.USER_ID = u.USER_ID)
```

El error que recibo es el siguiente:
**ORA-01861: literal does not match format string**

Esto es debido a los campos de la BBDD como podemos observar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ya que el ATTR_VALUE es tipo CLOB y no VARCHAR2, lo cual entra en conflicto.

¿Alguna solución para evitar este conflicto?
¿Se podría hacer un parse sobre DATE() en el SELECT?

Comment: Si sabes que es ese campo, podrías plantear la pregunta con un [mcve] con una consulta mucho más simple, sin olvidar incluir qué es lo que está almacenado en el campo de marras.

Answer (score 0):

Los LOB son tipos de datos especiales para guardar contenido de gran tamaño. Los BLOB almacenan datos binarios mientras que los CLOB almacenan caracteres.

Debido a su tamaño, las bases de datos suelen permitirte el acceso pero no suele ser fácil usar el contenido de ese LOB para filtrar resultados en una sentencia SQL.

Sin embargo, Oracle proporciona un paquete denominado DBMS_LOB que permite trabajar con estos tipos de datos.

En esta página tienes varios ejemplos [Ejemplo de DBMS_LOB](https://www.codifica.me/paquete-dbms_lob-iv-ejemplos/)

Lo que deberías hacer, (Al menos lo que yo veo como mejor opción) es convertir el CLOB en un VARCHAR2 mediante la opción dbms_lob.substr

La función [dbms_lob.substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349) va obteniendo una cadena de caracteres del tamaño que le indiques.
Para obtener una fecha te bastan 10 caracteres. Se obtendrían así

```sql
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (uav_last.ATTR_VALUE,10,1)
```

con lo que el TO_DATE que te está fallando lo podrías montar con algo como ésto

```sql
to_date(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (uav_last.ATTR_VALUE,10,1), 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```